# Number of numbers between 2 and 3 in IEEE-754

Tags: numbers, ieee-754, representation

i am learning IEEE-754 representation of numbers. I know how to convert from binary to IEEE and on vice versa. Now i am trying to figure out how to find out how many numbers in single precision are for instance between 2 and 3. So, the sign will be the same for both. Fraction will be a combination i think and exponent is dependent from a proper number(because of shifts). WHat would be a clever way to do it right ? I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [handy online IEEE-754 conversion utility](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html):

```
2.0 = 0x40000000
3.0 = 0x40400000
```

So:

```
0x40400000 - 0x40000000 = 0x400000 = 4194304
```

Answer: 4 million or so.

Comment: hey, i dont understand ur result. 0x400000. It 0x00400000 right? If so i am getting 5.877472E-39 in site u provided. Not 4 milions xD

Comment: The difference in binary representations tells you how many distinct values there are, i.e. we treat these values as if they were integers and then use the difference to get the result. `0x400000` as an *integer* is just over 4 million.