# Pointer casting

Tags: c, pointers

What this code mean? i mean it's seem that we take the address of a variable and cast it to a (pointer type), after that we deferencing it, as we will know the value. Am I wrong?

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {

  int numI = 3;
  float numF = * (float *)&numI;

  printf("%f", numF); 

  numF = 3.0;
  numI = * (int*)&numF;

  printf("\n%d", numI); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: violating strict aliasing rules can lead to strange things...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Related, but not exactly: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428118/2988730

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015 the results I get are 0.000000 and 1077936128. Watching the variables in the debugger, I see `numF` with an illegal float value which the `printf()` seems to be turning into zero for the first printed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these steps:

- `numI` and `numF` are 2 objects that happen to have the same size on your architecture, namely 4 bytes.
- `&numI` is an expression with type `int *` and its value is the address of the object `numI`.
- Casting it with `(float *)&numI` is an expression of type `float *` with the same value. Aking to telling the compiler, *this address is that of a `float`*.
- Dereferencing this expression `*(float *)&numI` produces a value of type `float` that depends on the actual representation of `int` for the value `3`. For example, on the intel core processors (little endian, 32-bit, 2s complement) the bytes at address `intI` would contain `03 00 00 00`. `float` objects are represented in memory on the same processor using the IEEE-756 Standard: `03 00 00 00` represents the **very** small value *1.5 x 2<sup>-148</sup>*, approximately *4.2039e-45*.
- Passing this value as variable argument to `printf` first converts it to type `double`, with the same value and `printf` converts the value to `0.000000` because the format `%f` specifies only 6 decimal places and no exponent. In order to get a more precise conversion, you could use `%g` which would produce `4.2039e-45`, or `%a` which would produce the hexadecimal representation `0x1.8p-148`.
- The second part of the program performs the opposite conversion: the `float` value `3.0F` whose IEEE-756 representation is `00 00 40 40` is reinterpreted as an `int`, producing the value `1077936128`.

Here is a modified version of your program that makes it more explicit:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int numI;
    float numF;
    unsigned char *p;

    assert(sizeof numI == sizeof numF);

    numI = 3;
    p = (unsigned char *)&numI;
    printf("int value %d is represented in memory as %02X %02X %02X %02X\n",
           numI, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);

    //numF = *(float *)&numI;
    memcpy(&numF, &numI, sizeof numF);
    printf("reinterpreted as float with format %%f: %f\n", numF);
    printf("reinterpreted as float with format %%g: %g\n", numF);
    printf("reinterpreted as float with format %%a: %a\n", numF);
    printf("numF exact value: %g * 2^-148\n", numF * pow(2.0, 148));

    numF = 3.0;
    p = (unsigned char *)&numF;
    printf("float value %.1g is represented in memory as %02X %02X %02X %02X\n",
           numF, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);

    //numI = *(int *)&numF;
    memcpy(&numI, &numF, sizeof numI);
    printf("reinterpreted as int with format %%d: %d\n", numI);
    printf("reinterpreted as int with format %%#X: %#X\n", numI);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
int value 3 is represented in memory as 03 00 00 00
reinterpreted as float with format %f: 0.000000
reinterpreted as float with format %g: 4.2039e-45
reinterpreted as float with format %a: 0x1.8p-148
numF exact value: 1.5 * 2^-148
float value 3 is represented in memory as 00 00 40 40
reinterpreted as int with format %d: 1077936128
reinterpreted as int with format %#X: 0X40400000
```

Note however that:

- These casts violate the strict aliasing rule, hence have undefined behavior.
- The representation in memory of types `int` and `float` are architecture specific. Some systems represent `int` with big-endian byte order, some have padding bits and trap values, some vintage systems even used one's complement or sign+magnitude representations. The representations for `float` can be even more exotic, although most current systems use IEEE-756 with the same byte ordering as integers. So your program has undefined behavior again, and at best produces implementation specific output.
- The recommended method for reinterpreting the representation in memory is to copy the bytes with `memcpy`, as shown in the modified code. Modern compilers will produce very efficient code for this, expanding the `memcpy` to a mere 2 instructions if not less.